# In C# and also Java, what's the relationship between Object[] and String[]?

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I recently started to think of this problem and I can't find the answer.
The following code compiles and executes as expected

```
object[] test = new string[12];
```

However, I don't know why.

I mean, should we consider string[] as the derived class of object[]?
I think in C#, every array is an instance of Array class. If Array is generic, it should be `Array<T>`, and `Array<string>` can be assigned to `Array<object>`, it doesn't make sense. I remember only interface can use in/out keyword.

And in Java, I'm not sure, but still feel weird. Why different types of references can be possibly assigned to each other when they don't have super-sub class relationship?

Can somebody explain a little?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because reference type arrays support covariance in both Java and C#. It also means that every write into a reference type array has to be checked at execution time, to make sure you don't write the wrong type of element into it :(

Don't forget that both Java and C# (and .NET in general) started off without generics. If they *had* had generics to start with, life could have been somewhat different.

Note that both Java and C# support generic variance now, but in rather different ways. So for example in C# 4 you can write:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = // Get some string sequence here
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

but you *can't* write

```
IList<string> strings = // Get some string list here
// Compile-time error: IList<T> isn't covariant in T
IList<object> objects = strings;
```

This wouldn't be safe, because you can *add* to an `IList<T>` as well as taking items from it.

This is a big topic - for more details, see [Eric Lippert's blog series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/).

Comment: Thank you. It explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In C# there is (and always been) covariance of arrays of reference-types. It still *is* a `string[]`, but you *can* legally cast it to an `object[]` (and access values as you would expect).

But try putting in an `int` (or any other non-string value) and you'll see that it still behaves appropriately (i.e. doesn't let you).

Comment: Thanks. I start to understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because object is the parent (or the superclass) for all other classes. Search for boxing/ unboxing for more data.

Comment: Covariance is the relevant mechanism here.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the really smart guys are talking about covariance and contravariance and I couldn't for the life of me explain (or understand) this stuff, listen to Eric Lippert:

[Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq)

Comment: This post really answers my question in detail (at least C# part). Thanks a lot.